# How do ds_lists function in gml? Are they global? Do I need to access them like a variable from other instances?

Tags: list, gml

I have this code

```
obj_Player.x = statePlayerX;
obj_Player.y = statePlayerY;
obj_Player.grv = stateGrav;

for(var i = 0; i < obj_ControlLevel1.platformNumb; ++i)
{
    ds_list_find_value(hList,i).x = ds_list_find_value(statePHX,i);
    ds_list_find_value(hList,i).y = ds_list_find_value(statePHY,i);
    ds_list_find_value(vList,i).x = ds_list_find_value(statePVX,i);
    ds_list_find_value(vList,i).y = ds_list_find_value(statePVY,i);
} // Line 11

with(obj_ControlLevel1) {
usedPlatforms = platformsNumbState;
}
```

But, I'm getting compile errors saying that line 11 has : unexpected symbol "." in expression

and that at line 11 : malformed assignment

For context: This code is going to be placed in a separate object from obj_ControlLevel1

The ds_lists hList and vList are held in another object and hold references to in-game objects the lists statePHX, statePHY, statePVX, statePVY

Answer (score 0):

I think the line 11 unexpected "." in the expression is referring to this part here:

for(var i = 0; **i < obj_ControlLevel1.platformNumb**; ++i)

I would try formatting it like this instead:

```
var platformNumb = obj_ControlLevel1.platformNumb;

for(var i = 0; i < platformNumb; ++i) {
      yourcodehere
}
```

To answer your question in the title, ds_lists are not necessarily global. You assign their index to a variable, which you could make a global variable, instance variable, or local variable.

```
list = ds_list_create();
Or
var list = ds_list_create();
Or
globalvar list;
list = ds_list_create();
```

Hope this helps!